# React Router v4 not rendering anything when files separated

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have been able to get this to work with a single file, but moving routes to a *route.js* results in the component not being rendered. Clearly I am missing something. I have looked at a lot of tutorials but they seems to all be for React Router < v4.0

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';

import routes from './routes.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Link to="/">/</Link><br />
      <Link to="/login">Login</Link><br />
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

// Hot Module Replacement API
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./Home/Home', () => {
    render(Home);
  });
}
```

*routes.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Home from './Home/Home';
import Login from './Login/Login';


export default (
  <Route path="/" component={Home}>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  </Route>
)
```

I have tried to actually have the bottom of *route.js* structured as below but i get an error

> Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Desired *route.js*

```
export default (
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
)
```

If I change this so that I have it all in *index.js* as below, everything works as expected.

Working *index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';

import Home from './Home/Home';
import Login from './Login/Login';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Link to="/">/</Link><br />
      <Link to="/login">Login</Link><br />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

// Hot Module Replacement API
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./Home/Home', () => {
    render(Home);
  });
}
```

To save the question from getting too long I have not initially pasted my component code. If this is helpful let me know in the comments.

If it also makes a difference I am using ExpressJS, Webpack and React Hot Loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have imported `routes` you have not used them in your component

Use

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Link to="/">/</Link><br />
      <Link to="/login">Login</Link><br />
    </div>
    {routes}
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

and your routes.js file will be

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Home from './Home/Home';
import Login from './Login/Login';


export default (
  <Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  </Switch>
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was going to be something simple that I was missing.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use switch in `route.js` to export single element. Switch ensures only one Route component is being rendered.

```
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

export default (
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
   </Switch>
)
```