# react router version 4 not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I checked [here][1] and [here][2] but it dint help me. I am using react-router version 4 and when I tried to run console also not showing anything nor my page. please help me out here I put one console that is also not printing anything means my headerContainer it self it not being rendered
here is my index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './stores/configureStores';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import{ Dashboard} from "./containers/HeaderContainer"

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
     <BrowserRouter >
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

my HeaderContainer

```
import React from "react"
import NavBar from "../components/Header/NavBar"

export default class HeaderContainer extends React.Component{
    render(){
        console.log("hello")
        return(
            <NavBar/>
        )
    }
}
```

and my navBar

```
import React from "react"
import Link from "react-router"

const navBar = ({props}) => (
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <Link to="/">
                    <img alt="snapstrat logo" src="../../../assets/images/Final_Badge.png"/>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/">DASHBOARD</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropbtn">PRO</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropbtn">PLA</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
)
export default navBar
```

UPDATE 1:
I edited my index.js like this way

```
import HeaderContainer from "./containers/HeaderContainer"

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
     <BrowserRouter >
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HeaderContainer}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368538/react-router-v4-not-rendering-anything-when-files-separated
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666170/react-router-version-4-not-showing-anything
```

Now m getting error like this

```
warning.js:35 Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?
    in nav (created by NavBar)
    in NavBar (created by HeaderContainer)
    in HeaderContainer (created by Route)
    in Route
    in Switch
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in Provider

invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `NavBar`.
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at instantiateReactComponent (instantiateReactComponent.js:74)
    at instantiateChild (ReactChildReconciler.js:44)
    at eval (ReactChildReconciler.js:71)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:77)
    at traverseAllChildren (traverseAllChildren.js:172)
    at Object.instantiateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:70)
    at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:185)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:224)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:703)
```

EDIT 2:
ok now I finally changed my index.js like this way

```
import {HeaderContainer} from "./containers/HeaderContainer"

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
     <BrowserRouter >
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HeaderContainer}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and my HeaderContainer like this

```
import {NavBar} from "../components/Header/NavBar"

export default class HeaderContainer extends React.Component{
    render(){
        console.log("hello")
        return(
            <NavBar/>
        )
```

Now I back to same position no error no rendering..:(

Comment: `warning.js:35 Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?` - invalid jsx, fix your NavBar component.

Comment: Ya done.but still same error

Comment: dude, your navbar is full of `class="` references. class is a reserved keyword in js - you need to use `className`.

Comment: I suggest you read this on how to import components https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/in-reactjs-when-should-i-add-brackets-when-import/41338672#41338672

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `Link` from `react-router-dom` in your Navbar component like

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
```

as `Link` is being moved to the `react-router-dom` package from v4 onwards.
See the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)

Also make sure to install `react-router-dom` before that using

```
npm install -S react-router-dom
```

and you are importing `Dashboard` as a named export from `HeaderContainer` component but it doesn't contain any named export called Dashboard.

I think you need to change it to

```
import Dashboard from "./containers/HeaderContainer"
```

Comment: hi I made both the changes I changed HeaderContainer from Dashboard and added {Link} but dint help..:(

Comment: What do you mean changes HeaderContainer from Dashboard. One more thing check that in `import NavBar from "../components/Header/NavBar"` , the path is correct

Comment: @LowCool, I'd suggest you use [codesanbox](https://medium.com/@housecor/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5) to demo what you're doing and save your time. I believe it's just a little thing to fix