# Module has no exported member 'Link'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Installed **react-router** like `npm --save react-router` and cant use Link.
 How can i fix it?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYbVm.png)

Comment: Thanks all. Sorry for that question, im newbie in React and didnt find any information of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react router version 4 not rendering anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412714/react-router-version-4-not-rendering-anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to import react-router-dom to use `Link` in V4

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4648

Answer (score 1):

You needs [react-router-dom](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom):

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React for web, Try this

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```